# Sending and receiving data in parallel on socket android

Tags: android, performance, sockets

I am currently working on file transfer between two mobile devices. For this, i am using socket communication. On socket using DataInput and Data Output Stream, i am able to get approximately 6 MB/s speed. But as per my use case user can select all images, videos, apk's, documents to transfer. so let's say user selected 2GB data to transfer with my app he has to wait for more than 6 minutes. so I have done some modifications.
1] On receiver side I opened up 5 ports (one for image, one for video and so on)
2] Sender will send appropriate files on corresponding ports.
3] I am sending all the files at a time parallelly using async task and receiver is receiving data in 5 different thread.

But the problem is speed still is same for 2GB it's approximately 6MB/s.
So my question is:
1] Will multiport socket increase performance?
2] if I am doing something wrong, then how can I send data parallelly on different ports on a socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android devices cannot go more than 7mb/s as per my experience. Use some data monitor start file transfer on lan. You will notice its maximum speed is approximately 7mb.
Sorry i cannot comment yet so added as answer.

Comment: Maybe bcoz of their chips are not capable to go beyound that.

Comment: You can also send data parallelly on same port using multiple threads.

Comment: but how the receiver will distinguish between data? as all data is in bytes. plus will this improve the speed of transfer?

Comment: You can design your own protocol. Like send a string first "filetype:filename" then split that string on other side to distiguish what is about to get transfered. You can also send file size or anything you want in one single string.

Comment: i don't think it will be faster or slower in either case.

Comment: Accept it as answer if you found this info helpful